# Why the text appears outside it's container?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">Outside div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
   width   : 100px;
   height  : 100px;
}
#div1{
   background-color  : lightblue;
   float             : left;
}
#div2{
    background-color : blue; 
}
```

I've two `<div>` with fixed size. One is `float:left` and the other is not. Both `<div>`'s are displayed at the same position. But the text inside the second `<div>` appear outside its `<div>` container. Why?

If I put `overflow:auto` on `#div2` the second `<div>` appears at a different position next to the first one. I don't understand what happens here.

http://jsfiddle.net/c86LS/

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: It's not for a real page, I'm trying to understand the reasons of this behavior. I want to understand the rules of the css rendering engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, div1 and div2 cover the same space. The line box with the text in must avoid the float, so since the overflow on div2 is the default "visible", the text flow continues as if the div2 box was taller than it is, displaying below the boxes.

In the second case, setting div2 overflow to "auto" causes div2 to form a new block formatting context. This means that it starts, not at the same place as div1, but next to it, so you see the whole of div1 and div2.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer. But why `overflow:auto` causes a new block formating context? What is the computed value of `auto`?

Comment: From [CSS 2.1 Section 9.4.1 Block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) ".. block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' ... establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.". It's just what the rules say to do. Reputedly, because it would be just too hard to implement otherwise. The computed value of "auto" in this case is just "auto".

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden` property for the parent div.

Comment: It's not for a real page, I'm trying to understand the reasons of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any width for the #div1. So that it is occupying the entire width of it parent. Assign some width for the #div1 then the blue container will use the remaining part.

```
 #div1{
 background-color: lightblue;
 float: left;
 width:50px;
 }
```

Comment: `div{ width:100px; height:100px;}` will give a width to `#div1`

Comment: yes. if you have not assigned any width then it will treat 100%. So here #div1 took all 100px width.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you didn't cleared it. when ever you float elements and do not clear it properly it causes issues in heights. the preceding div do not take complete height.